# WSO2 Identity Server XACML JSON Request results in "Indeterminate" [Couldn't find AttributeDesignator attribute]

Tags: json, authorization, xacml, entitlements, abac

I am try to send a JSON request to wso2 entitlement endpoint using POSTMAN

Here is my published policy in the identity server:

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" PolicyId="samplePolicy" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:deny-overrides" Version="1.0">
    <Target>
        <AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
                <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                    <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">
                                             read
                                        </AttributeValue>
                    <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                </Match>
            </AllOf>
        </AnyOf>
    </Target>
    <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="permit"/>
```

Here is JSON request I send:

```
    {
    "Request": {
        "Action": {
            "Attribute": [
                {
                    "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
                    "Value": "read"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Resource": {
            "Attribute": [
                {
                    "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id",
                    "Value": "http://127.0.0.1/service/very_secure/"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Both blocks of the code came from this blog
https://medium.com/@gdrdabarera/how-entitlement-management-works-with-rest-api-via-xacml-in-wso2-identity-server-5-3-0-7a60940d040c#.4lxgiw6tn

But no matter what I tried it always give me "Indeterminate" response

[Postman response screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4FDL.png)

I also try my own policy and request but I always get the same response

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed with: Remove any white space before and after the "read" attribute value in the xml policy:

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyId="samplePolicyforJSON" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:deny-overrides" Version="1.0">
   <Target>
      <AnyOf>
         <AllOf>
            <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
            </Match>
         </AllOf>
      </AnyOf>
   </Target>
   <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="permit"></Rule>
</Policy>
```

Tested with:

XACML Request:

```
{
    "Request": {
        "Action": {
            "Attribute": [
                {
                    "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
                    "Value": "read"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Resource": {
            "Attribute": [
                {
                    "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id",
                    "Value": "http://127.0.0.1/service/very_secure/"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

XACML Response:

```
{
  "Response": [
    {
      "Decision": "Permit",
      "Status": {
        "StatusCode": {
          "Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And with:

XACML Request:

```
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false">
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
           <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">http://localhost/secureAccess/resource</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>   
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
</Request>
```

XACML Response:

```
<Response xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17">
    <Result>
        <Decision>Permit</Decision>
        <Status>
            <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"/>
        </Status>
    </Result>
</Response>
```

Comment: Actually the extra space is not in my policy. It is just the error in my post. I manage to solve the problem by restarting the server. Thank anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you followed all the steps correctly, It should work.
After adding the policy, please check whether the policy is correctly added. 
eg. Remove unnecessary spaces in the policy

Publish it to the PDP correctly and try. You can also try in "try" option in the policy window in IS 5.3.0. Use only xml request because it does not works for JSON